# Реально ли одним запросом удалить все пустые категории из БД MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii, laravel

Здравствуйте.

Пишу на PHP, база данных MySQL.

Есть сущность категории (таблица categories, поля id и name), есть сущность продукта (таблица products, поля id и name) и связаны они связью многие ко многим (таблица product_category, поля id, category_id и product_id).

У меня есть задача, которая звучит достаточно просто: "Необходимо удалить все пустые категории".

Я использую фреймворк Laravel и самое простое, что лезет в голову это запросить все категории с продуктами (через связь) и затем в цикле удалять каждую категорию, которая не содержит продуктов.

Но я никак не придумаю как это сделать одним запросом. Подобрать условие выборки пустых категорий и удалить все записи в таблице categories, подходящие под это условие.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Меня также интересует этот вопрос, но проверка показывает, что запрос работает как то не так. В запросе отсутствует упоминание о третей таблице, она нам не нужна?

Comment: Привет. О каком конкретно запросе вы говорите? По подробнее, пожалуйста :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае с laravel, можно использовать `has` или `whereHas` методы 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Учитывая, что я пишу код с использованием Laravel, то для меня это самый подходящий вариант :-) Что-то я не обратил особого внимания на данное нововведение.

Comment: @ИванТоргов по чаще в документацию заглядывайте)

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE A.*
  FROM categories A
  JOIN (select C.id
          from categories C
          left join products P
            on P.category_id=C.id
         where P.id is NULL
       ) B
     ON A.id=B.id
```

Перед удалением убедитесь, что внутренний подзапрос возвращает id тех категорий которые подлежат удалению.

Comment: Спасибо! Мне как-то рассказывали про вложенные запросы, но сам их никогда не применял на практике. Теперь знаю когда они необходимы :-)